# wso2 BAM: Authentication failed! admin-bam

Tags: authentication, wso2, wso2-bam

When I change admin-bam password from Web Console ( the default password for admin-bam is "admin"),

```
Home > Configure > Users and Roles --> Change my Password.
```

Then I recive the following log errors:

```
TID: [0] [BAM] [2015-11-04 08:36:07,718] INFO
{org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} - user admin-bam connected {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge}

TID: [0] [BAM] [2015-11-04 08:36:07,733] ERROR
{org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.authentication.Authenticator} - Authentication failed! admin-bam. This user is not permitted to publish events. {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.authentication.Authenticator}
```

I also change my usr-mgt.xml and restart BAM, but I receive the same error:

```
<Realm>
<Configuration>
<AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>
<AdminRole>admin-bam</AdminRole>
<AdminUser>
<UserName>admin-bam</UserName>
<Password>NEW_PASSWORD_HERE</Password>
</AdminUser>
<EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users       in      this role sees the registry root -->
Property name="dataSource">jdbc/USER_LST</Property>
</Configuration>
-.........
```

If I set again admin-bam/admin, those logs disappear.

Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use in the following way

```
Configure > Users and Roles > Users > Change Password
```

Comment: Thanks.Yes I tried what you say. I also tried Configure --> Users and Roles --> Change My Password and Configure > Users and Roles > Users > Change Password (for admin-bam) . I got the same result

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the BAMUsername and BAMPassword to match the new username and passowrd which you defined. Configuration is given below,

```
<APIUsageTracking>
<!-- Enable/Disable the API usage tracker. -->
<Enabled>true</Enabled>   
<PublisherClass>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher</PublisherClass>
<ThriftPort>7614</ThriftPort> 
<BAMServerURL>tcp://<BAM host IP>:7614/</BAMServerURL>
<BAMUsername>admin</BAMUsername>
<BAMPassword>admin</BAMPassword>
<!-- JNDI name of the data source to be used for getting BAM statistics. This data source should
    be defined in the master-datasources.xml file in conf/datasources directory. -->
<DataSourceName>jdbc/WSO2AM_STATS_DB</DataSourceName>
</APIUsageTracking>
```

You can find this file in following location:
API Manager/repository/conf/api-manager.xml

If you are in a clustered environment, it is sufficient to only change the above settings in the Gateway node.

Comment: Thanks for your support.

Comment: API Manager/repository/conf/api-manager.xml doesn´t exist, but  API Manager/repository/conf/user-manager.xml  I have set  <UserManager>
    <Realm>
        <Configuration>
                <AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>
                <AdminRole>admin-bam</AdminRole>
                <AdminUser>
                     <UserName>admin-bam</UserName>
                     <Password>NEW_PASSWORD_HERE</Password>
                </AdminUser>


but it doesn´t work

Comment: Please provide the product that you are trying to configure with WSO2 BAM along with it's version numbers.